# How to get document with the revision attribute in pouchdb?

Tags: javascript, electron, pouchdb

I am building an app with the electron framework using pouchdb. Some values in my database are changing over time and I want to see them without creating new documents with each new update. That way I want to use revisions as they are being created from new every time I update a doc.

The question is how can I fetch a document just using its revision.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem on my own. For those having the same issue I post my solution here:

```
var pdb = new PouchDB('./test20');  // init of database

/* if I call function changes() it gives me the changes of a specific 
   with a specific ID*/

function changes() {
  console.log("Currently in: changes()");
  var idPlayer = ""+localStorage.getItem("playerIDLocalStorage");

  pdb.get(idPlayer, {revs_info: true}).then(function (revs) {  
    var x = 0;

    while(revs._revs_info[x].rev != null) {
      var revision = ""+revs._revs_info[x].rev;

      pdb.bulkGet({
        docs: [{id: idPlayer, rev: revision}],
        include_docs: true
      }).then(function (result) {
        var doc = result.results[0].docs[0].ok;
        console.log(doc.playerName);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Error in subchanges(): "+err);
      });
      x++;
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Error in changes(): "+err);
  });
}
```